# Android Manifest - how to specify the 4 diff image files and where to put them in the app?

Tags: android

I am looking at these Android instructions: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_launcher.html#size

and I made the 4 image sizes, but how do I specify them in the Android Manifest file? And where do I place the images within the code base?

So far I have this

```
  <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
                android:theme="@style/CustomTheme" >
```

But not sure how to specify the specific sizes of the launches icons and when they need to show up.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to write anything on manifest file.
You need to put images on related drawable folders like:

```
res\drawable-hdpi\ic_launcher.png 
res\drawable-mdpi\ic_launcher.png  
res\drawable-ldpi\ic_launcher.png 
res\drawable-xhdpi\ic_launcher.png
```

Comment: Just to add, latest SDK added `res/drawable-xhdpi/` for high resolution tablets and stuff.

Comment: Thank you - so I just have to replace the current default image in those directory and have the new images with the original name that is currently there, right? I'll accept your answer when SO allows me.

Comment: yep, you can replace default images in directories with yours and it will be good.

Comment: Just so I dont mess it up, rename the new images to the names of the old images? Or it doesn't matter?

Comment: It doesn't matter but ic_launcher name is the default naming convention for application launcher icon. Better use it like that but in reality it doesn't matter.

Comment: Also you can check this page: (Use common naming conventions for icon assets)  http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html

Comment: btw where should the xhdpi go? Should I make a seperate directory for it?

Comment: You can create a new directory under res folder like others. (drawable-xhdpi)

Comment: Awesome, ty!!  The link you posted is very useful btw :)

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to specify it in `Manifest` File, place them in `drawable-hdpi`, `drawable-mdpi` and `drawable-ldpi` folders depending upon the resolution, you can create one more folder `drawable-xhdpi` to support new High density screens like those like Google Nexus

Answer (score 1):

You have to place images in folder res/drawable-hdpi, res/drawable-ldpi, res/drawable-mdpi and 
change the name "icon" to your_name in the below code in Android Manifest.

```
 <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
```